# CMS для Интернет-магазина

Tags: cms

Посоветуйте оптимальную CMS для простенького Интернет-магазина. Желательно бесплатную.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первое, что в голову приходит: CMS Joomla и плагин [Virtuemart](http://virtuemart.net/).

Comment: <strike>плагин</strike> компонент

Answer (score 2):

Из того, что я видел, самый низкий порог вхождения и нетребовательность к ресурсам у Simpla http://simplacms.ru/

Answer (score 1):

Интернет-магазин можно организовать на WordPress ([WP e-Commerce Plugin](http://getshopped.org/))

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте [DotPlant2](https://github.com/devgroup-ru/dotplant2) - это открытая CMS для интернет-магазина на основе Yii Framework 2.

Answer (score 0):

Prestashop или booot cms. Все же больше склоняюсь к Prestashop, так как эта cms создана именно для инет магазина и ресурсов кушает меньше, нежели джумла, да и функционал получше...

Comment: Поддерживаю

Answer (score 0):

Поддерживаю gympi - CMS Joomla и плагин Virtuemart самый лучший вариант. Есть все необходимое для организации хорошо отлаженого магазина, и главное - все бесплатно. Также на своем опыте могу посоветовать Prestashop и более простую cms (но не менее функциональную) ShopOS, которую сам с успехом использую.

Answer (score 0):

ImageCMS Shop
Гибкая, функций достаточно и на бесплатной версии.

Answer (score 0):

Все зависит от предпочитаемого языка, на Python (Django) есть очень достойный CMS https://github.com/divio/django-shop

Answer (score 0):

Если вы - конечный пользователь продукта, то ставьте Bitrix.

Объясняю почему:

- Большое комьюнити
- Нет проблем, с поиском специалиста для доработок/внедрения нового функционала
- Огромный маркетплейс с готовыми решениями
- Она (CMS) работает!!!

Минусы:

- Платная
- Абсолютно уродский с точки зрения грамотного программиста код

Если  собираетесь разрабатывать продукт, то посмотрите что-нибудь более профессиональное - modX revolution, Yii или Wordpress.